# Issue with Markdown emphasis on characters within brackets (Gitlab.com)

Tags: encoding, markdown, gitlab, italic

I am not a coder, so consider myself a big rookie with Git tools and services like Gitlab.com, however I've noticed that when I read a .md file on Gitlab, it won't italicize chains of characters when they directly follow an opening bracket `(`, while it did work with Bitbucket and Github.

If I write `(*e.g.*`, the .md viewed on Gitlab will show `(*e.g.*` instead of (*e.g.*, which is a big issue for me as I intend to use Markdown to write academic papers (and take advantage of the Gitlab versioning, among other things) and often need italics. Any ideas on how to solve that? Is HTML the only way to italicize first words in brackets on Gitlab.com? Closing brackets `)` do not block the emphasis, only opening brackets `(` do.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi did you try using underscores or perhaps putting a space between the bracket and italicized text?  Sorry my only experience has been with github so this may or may not be helpful to you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be resolved in latest version. I created a playground repo, also tested on wiki.

- https://gitlab.com/axil/playground/blob/master/README.md
- https://gitlab.com/axil/playground/wikis/home

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for investing that again axil. :)